# widget.routeName must be a String beginning with forward slash (/)

Tags: flutter

Am having an issue, after updating my flutter I started to have a problem with the splashscreen which is giving me this error. **widget.routeName must be a String beginning with forward slash (/)** I have already updated the package but the error prevails.

```
class StartupView extends StatelessWidget {
  final PushNotificationService _pushNotificationService =locator<PushNotificationService>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _pushNotificationService.initialise();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    //Keep the app alive.
    Wakelock.enable();

    return ViewModelBuilder<StartupViewModel>.reactive(
      /* onModelReady: (model) =>model.handleStartUpLogic(),*/
      builder:(context, model, child) => SplashScreen(
        seconds: 3,
        navigateAfterSeconds:
        model.userId==null ? LoginView():HomeView(userId: model.userId,),
        title: new Text(
          'Peças & Acessórios',
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
        ),
        imageBackground: AssetImage('assets/images/otpImage.jpg'),
        image: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
        photoSize: 40.0,
        onClick: () => print(""),
        loaderColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      viewModelBuilder: ()=>locator<StartupViewModel>(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the part of your code that configures the routes your app supports

Answer (score 5):

check your splashScreen version :

`splashscreen: ^1.3.3`

and after add a `rootName` argument in yours Splashscreen:

```
SplashScreen(
        seconds: 3,
        routeName: "/",
        navigateAfterSeconds:
        model.userId==null ? LoginView():HomeView(userId: model.userId,),
        title: new Text(
          'Peças & Acessórios',
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
        ),
        imageBackground: AssetImage('assets/images/otpImage.jpg'),
        image: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
        photoSize: 40.0,
        onClick: () => print(""),
        loaderColor: Colors.white,
      ),
```